# YiiMongodbSuite count doesnt work

Tags: php, mongodb, yii, yii-extensions

I'm lost at this point.

Here is what i have:

```
$criteria = new \EMongoCriteria();
$criteria->userId = new \MongoID($userId);
$criteria->expiresAt = array('>' => new \MongoDate(time()));
```

Then I'm running this:

```
$model->count($criteria);
```

And it always returns 0 when i know that there are documents that meet this criteria.
Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

`findAllByAttributes()` with the same criteria works perfectly. But I don't need those documents i need to count them.

Answer (score 1):

When setting criteria field as property it uses simple comparision (`field == value`). You should set this criteria by *calling* field, like that:

```
$criteria->expiresAt('>', new \MongoDate(time()));
```

**NOTE**: Passing criteria to `findAllByAttributes` in wrong, it is not intended to work with `EMongoCriteria`, but with simple array. If you want to use criteria object pass it to `findAll` method.